# iPhone X safe area size

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I am trying to upgrade my app for iPhone X. I am not using auto-layout, constraints or safe area.

When I run my app on iPhone X simulator, this what I get:

[image]

My layout is in yellow area. On different model of iPhone it starts just below bar with time and battery status (y position 20 px). But on iPhone X it starts much lower and i cannot place anything in black areas. Does anybody know if there is way to get rid of these black bars? From documentation

I understood that you shouldn't place anything to close to corners, but this is way too much space.

Comment: You have different options, but if you don't want to use auto-layout, constraints and safe area, then the easiest is to use safe area margins programmatically.